# Laravel Livewire component is not refreshing when the data is updated

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

products cards in the loop and add to basket button Livewire component after data update all HTML is mixed

```
@forelse ($products as $productItem)
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
            .........
            <livewire:add-to-basket-button :product-id="$productItem->id" />
        </div>
    </div>
@empty
    .......
@endforelse
```

```
any idea ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `key()/wire:key` to nested components in a loop

try

```
@livewire('your-component', ['id' => $id], key($id))
```